# Oauth permanent token when authenticating via social login

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, laravel-socialite

I have a web and android applications. I want both apps to login users using their social media handles. I want to use

- google
- facebook
- twitter
- tiktok
- apple

I have looked at how facebook authenticates users from the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/

and there is `userID` which i assume will never ever change for any given user.

Since social media handles change, email addresses and usernames, is there a permanent account identifier token that the Oauth specification returns that uniquely identifies an account?

Comment: the response token returned by a social login should contain a sub claim.  This is the internal user id on the identity server you are connecting to.

Comment: Does the internal user id change ever?

Comment: it shouldn't no its how we preform account linking.  If you have an internal user id you can link the users accounts between different social media platforms using this subject id on the external system